# Elides junction table, how do I insert a row without querying the database for the entities referenced by the row?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ef-database-first, junction-table

Let's say we have a simple schema:

```
Employee
--------
Id
EmployeeName


Project
-------
Id
ProjectName


EmployeeProject
---------------
EmployeeId
ProjectId
```

In a previous version of EF, I remember the junction table getting added to the model (or maybe it was always elided and I'm thinking of a table that had additional columns). In EF 6, the table is elided and the model looks like this:

[image: EF Model]

Is there any way to add rows to the junction table without first querying the database to get the appropriate entity? E.g., if I want to create a new Project, I might get a list of Employee Ids from the front-end; I would have to query the database to get the Employees, and then add them to the Project's Employee collection, and then hit the database again to save. Is there a way to do that with only one call to the database?

**Update**

Here's an example of what I'm trying to solve (pseudocode):

```
CreateProject (string name, List<int> employeeIds)
{
    var proj = new Project;
    proj.ProjectName = name;
    context.Projects.Add(proj);

    foreach(var id in employeeIds)
    {
        // we have the id, but we need to get the actual Employee entity by hitting the database
        var employee = context.Employees.First(e => e.Id == id); 
        proj.Employees.Add(employee);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If the junction table existed in the model, I could simply do:

```
CreateProject (string name, List<int> employeeIds)
{
    var proj = new Project;
    proj.ProjectName = name;
    context.Projects.Add(proj);

    foreach(var id in employeeIds)
    {
        var empProj = new EmployeeProject();
        empProj.Project = proj;

        // we don't have the Employee entity, but we can set the Id and everything works.
        empProj.EmployeeId = id;  

        context.EmployeeProjects.Add(empProj);
    }

    context.SaveChanges();  // only need to hit database once, after all entities have been added
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **don't have to** retrieve the items first. When working with disconnected object, you can just attach the existing entity or change the state to `Unchanged`.

> Entity Framework takes care of tracking the state of entities while
>   they are connected to a context, but in disconnected or N-Tier
>   scenarios you can let EF know what state your entities should be in.

More: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676

You can just attach the employee to reduce database round trip.

```
foreach(var id in employeeIds)
{
    var employee = new Employe { Id = id }; 
    db.Set<Employee>().Attach(employee); // context.Entry(employee).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    proj.Employees.Add(employee);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EF takes care of it all for you; you can ignore it. Just add the employee to the Project.Employees collection and/or the Project to the Employee.Projects collection and it will take cate of the junction table for you. The same when deleting: just remove objects from the collections and the junction table rows will be deleted.

EDIT after clarification:
If you're working with EF objects, an instance of an existing EF object has to be got via EF. When using EF you don't keep a list of Employee Ids around; you keep a list of Enployees. EF tracks things it knows about: if you just create a blank object and fill in stuff, EF will think its a new one.

Comment: That's the thing though, I have to make a call to the database to get the "Employee" entity from the id. If the multiplicity was 1 on the Project side (that is, Project had a column EmployeeId), I could set either Project.Employee or Project.EmployeeId, depending on which I had available. I've added some sample code to the question that shows the problem more clearly.

Comment: Your pseudo-code looks about right. What problem is it giving you?

Comment: Sorry: I was looking at trhe second example with the EmployeeProject object6: that on'e wrong and won't work as the model doesn't have an EmployeeProject class (but knows that the table exists). The first set on pseudo-code does look fine. What problem does it give you?

Comment: This line `var employee = context.Employees.First(e => e.Id == id); ` makes a call to the database. The question asks "how do I insert a row **without** querying the database for the entities referenced by the row?". The second sample would accomplish that, but as you said that class doesn't exist.

Comment: OK. That wasn't clear to me. If you're working with EF objects, an instance of an existing EF object has to be got via EF. When using EF you don't keep a list of Employee Ids around; you keep a list of Enployees.

Comment: Ok cool, so the answer is "not possible". If you modify yours to say something along those lines I'll accept :)  Also, now I see the relevant documentation: "You can choose to use one or both types of associations in your model. However, if you have a pure many-to-many relationship that is connected by a join table that contains only foreign keys, the EF will use an independent association to manage such many-to-many relationship" ([src](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)). Seems odd that they would give you the choice in one case but not in the other.